# pspdfkit - text boxes combining and alignment issues

Tags: pdf, editor, pspdfkit

We've been having a tough time using pspdfkit for our project due to:

1. text disappearing
2. text boxes being combined
3. text box alignment
4. paragraph boxes being converted to single lines of text

Here are a couple videos that show these issues....

PSPDFKit PDF editor problems with editing and comparison to Adobe Acrobat editing
https://youtu.be/-1uYkqxej7I

PSPDFKit - PDF editor bug - all text disappearing
https://youtu.be/nHlfKvC7o7k

PSPDFKit PDF editor alignment problems
https://youtu.be/slquBubPqis

Curious if others are having these same issue and what can be done to solve this problems....

Using content editor web standalone we've tried modifying some of the editor options and variables.  We've also tried adjusting the source PDFs to have more spacing for text boxes or different fonts for each text box to try to trick PSPDFKit's system into creating separate text boxes for each item.  These issue still plague the system and we are not able to use this tool for our purposes.